# How to Search and and Apply filter query on on Jsob columns postgre sql?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am using laravel and postgresql, I have column in my user table which is language with type jsonb.

I want to apply like query on this .

I am tries with select jsonb_array_elements_text(languages) where languages like '%1%' but it is not working .

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem will increase your chances of getting good answers. When it comes to asking about `laravel` it is best to show your `Eloquent` queries to see where you are having problems. Please see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#json-where-clauses for querying json columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question properly, but if you simply want to select all rows where a json/jsonb column contains "1", then you can retype the json/jsonb column to text and use *LIKE* on its text representation.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE languages::TEXT LIKE '%1%';
```